# joins on multiple table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I'm new to MySQL database. I want to join two tables and fetch the count. For example:

**Table A**

```
_id       content
 1         aaa
 2         bbb
 3         ccc
 4         ddd
```

**Table B**

```
_id      a_id       b_content
 1         1          aaa
 2         1          bbb
 3         1          ccc
 4         2          ddd
 5         2          eee
 6         2          fff
 7         3          ggg
 8         3          aaa
 9         3          bbb
 10        3          ccc
 11        3          ddd
```

Now my resultant table should have:

**Table C**

```
a_id   a_content   count
1        aaa         3
2        bbb         3
3        ccc         5
4        ddd         0
```

How this is possible with joins?

Comment: I have used this query `SELECT a._id, a.content FROM A a
   JOIN B b
            ON b.a_id= a._id 
            GROUP BY a._id` but it will give me only 3 columns (not include the rows which are having 0 in count field)

Comment: Please do some research before posting any question. You need to use inner join ,group by  clause and count function to get your desired output.

Comment: `SELECT a._id, a.content, a.title, a.createdon, count(c.forumid) FROM forums a
   JOIN comments c
            ON c.forumid = a._id 
            GROUP BY a._id` Sorry I've commented wrong query

Comment: You need another join method. You need to do some more self studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will give the resultant

```
SELECT a._id as a_id, a.content as a_content, (SELECT count(*) FROM table_b AS b WHERE b.a_id = a._id) as count FROM table_a AS a
```

Comment: thanks, It worked for me

Comment: As in question it was mentioned that how this is possible with joins so here is the solution with join.

SELECT TableB.a_id,TableA.content,count(TableB.a_id) as Count FROM TableA
inner join Tableb on Tableb.a_id = tableA._id
group by Tableb.a_id,TableA.content